# fb login button not appearing in webpage

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to integrate fb login in my website.i am using the code given by the facebook developer tools window.Following is the code snippet.fb login button is not appearing in the webpage after using the code.Please guide me whats wrong in code and how can i correct that..

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false">
<fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think your js code  not looking proper so try my code that i posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use this code it will solve your isssue

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/999mfqsv/)

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=334884309994095&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false"></div>
```